# How to change windows services account domain name and password using powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, clearcase

We are in the ClearCase windows domain migration phase. Now we migrated the domain but how to change clearcase_albd account domain name and password using power-shell script in user machine. I'm very new to powershell scripting.

Old Domain Name: Old_Domain
New Domain Name: New_Domain

Old Account: dragon
New Account: dragon_fire

I googled it but it didn't help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find your service:

```
$service = gwmi win32_service -computer [computername] -filter "name='service name'"
```

And then set the credentials:

```
$service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"username","password")
```

Or use the script: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amantaras/2014/12/10/powershell-script-to-change-windows-service-credentials/

Comment: That's works perfect. I have one more concern , I don't want to keep the password in plain text. I mean encrpyt the password and replace plain text "password" to "encrypted password".